# How do I use word-spacing in this type of situation?

Tags: html, css, text, word-spacing

```css
.front-button {
  font-family: 'Bebas Neue';
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}

.front-button span {
  word-spacing: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="front-button">
  <span>
    <a href="#">CUSTOMIZE</a>
    <a href="#">DESIGNS</a>
    <a href="#">PLANS</a>
  </span>
  <a href="#">ABOUT US</a>
</div>
```

I want to separate the text customize, designs, plans and about us
but when I use word spacing the space between about us also gets larger.
I've tried using span and I don't know if I'm using it correctly.

Comment: Your problem was the `<span>` opening tag was mistplaced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you aren't wanting to space out individual words, you are wanting to have space between your anchor (a) elements. So give each of them a margin left and right.

```css
.front-button {
  font-family: 'Bebas Neue';
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}

.front-button a {
  margin: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="front-button">
  <a href="#">CUSTOMIZE</a>
  <a href="#">DESIGNS</a>
  <a href="#">PLANS</a></span>
  <a href="#">ABOUT US</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe using `margin` would have been a better idea

```css
.front-button {
  font-family: 'Bebas Neue';
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}

.front-button a {
  margin-right: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="front-button">
  <a href="#">CUSTOMIZE</a>
  <a href="#">DESIGNS</a>
  <a href="#">PLANS</a>
  <a href="#">ABOUT US</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! wish i could give you a thumbs up but i dont have enough reputation yet sorry.